# Issue appending to xml from html using SimpleXML

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to do a simple append to an existing `XML` document using `SimpleXML` in `PHP`. I have an `HTML` form that calls a `PHP` script that tries to append data to an already existing `XML` document in the same directory.

I have tried the basic implementation of this, but I keep getting the follow error:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): Cannot add child. Parent is 
not a permanent member of the XML tree in 
/the/directory/to/the/site/generate.php on line 
9

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addChild() on 
null...
```

Here is the already existing `XML` file that is being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tasks>
  <users/>
  <taskList>
    <tasks id="1234">
      <activities>
        <activity/>
      </activities>
    </task>
  </taskList>
</tasks>
```

Here is the `PHP` code:

```
<?php

$file = 'tasks.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$activities = $xml->activities;

$activity = $activities->addChild('activity');
$activity->setAttribute('id', '45678');
$activity->addChild('assigned', 'Jon');
$activity->addChild('priority', 'low');

$xml->asXML($file);
```

I am hard coding the values in just to get the append to work, but eventually these values will be from a submitted `html` form.

Any ideas as to why this is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  Firstly your XML is invalid, your close tag should be `</tasks>`.

When you try and get the `<activities>` tag in

```
$activities = $xml->activities;
```

this is trying to find the tag just off the root of the document, you could use the full path

```
$activities = $xml->taskList->tasks->activities;
```

or use (I have in this code) XPath to find it, this also allows you to pick out (if neccessary) which `<tasks>` tag you use depending of id.

```
$activities = $xml->xpath("//activities")[0];

$activity = $activities->addChild('activity');
$activity->addAttribute('id', '45678');
$activity->addChild('assigned', 'Jon');
$activity->addChild('priority', 'low');
```

You also use `setAttribute()` which doesn't exist - as the code shows it is `addAttribute()`.